# Updating html value without page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

How can I update the ejs objects without reloading the whole page? I am getting the data from the server via jquery, however I don't know how can I update the `title` object from saying `Express` to `NewTitle` in ejs template. On a side note, if somebody knows a good resource which can help a beginner in express Nodejs, please mention it.

**index.ejs:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="pageTitle"><%= title %></h1>
    <p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>

    <script type = "text/javascript"
            src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {

      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myButton").bind('click', function() {

          event.preventDefault();
          var data = $('#myEditText').val();
          var result = $.post('/yolo', {textBoxValue: data}, function(callback) {
            alert("data: "+ callback.title);
              $(document).ready(function(){
                  title = callback.title;
              });
          });

        });
      });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.js:**

```
router.post('/yolo', jsonParser, function(req, res, next) {

    res.send('index', { title: 'NewTitle'})
    console.log("hello inside index.js method 1");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't update the Ejs variable via Jquery, you should use something like this:

HTML

```
<p>Welcome to <span class="title"><%= title %></span></p>
```

JS:

```
[...]
var result = $.post('/yolo', {
    textBoxValue: data
}, function(callback) {
    alert("data: " + callback.title);
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.title').html(callback.title);
    });
});
[...]
```

And you have to use `res.json({title: 'NewTitle'})` in Node.js instead `res.send()`

Comment: Is it necessary to put the required html tag in `span`?

Comment: You can use whatever you want but you need to find the element to be changed (that one containing the title)

Comment: Can you link me to a resource/website/videos that are noob friendly and will let me learn express node js with examples? I am a mobile developer and have no idea about server side dev, so I am asking

Comment: There are too many and I don't know what you have to do with it, Google will help you better than me for this.